# c/c++ - safest way to send time_t over socket

Tags: c++, c, time, network-programming

I've set up a C++ server/client environment, and am trying to send a time_t value from the server to the client (an useful thing in any server). But I'm coming accross a headache: time_t seems to not be under any size specifications. I'm wondering what is the safest (more portable) way to send time_t over the network.

This is a little example:

```
time_t T = time(NULL);
unsigned char * P = (unsigned char *)&T;
// ... Convert it to network byte order, etc.

// Here, 's' would be the socket, and 'S'
// the size of the data that is going to
// be sent
send(s, P, S, 0);
```

I have two problems:

- time_t is not size-fixed
- time_t can be a typedef of a signed or unsigned integral data type

How can I handle that two issues so that I can send it safely between (almost) any architecture?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: After seeing the same three answers, I find it better to response here. I'm sorry I did not clarify that before. I prefer sending it in 'pure' bytes, although sending it as a string is not a problem. As far as I understand, I would need to keep in mind (again) the signedness and the size of time_t data type in the host system, isn't it? (thanks and sorry)

Comment: Send the size of the data in a unified format (`uint32_t`, anyone?) as well, and also send a boolean value about its signedness.

Comment: @H2CO3 What if time_t is 8 bytes in the server and 4 bytes in the client?

Comment: Does sending the value as string cause a problem?

Comment: Hint: you may look at PTPv2 (Precision Timing Protocol) implementation [here](http://code.google.com/p/ptpv2d/wiki/PTPCCodeOverview) or [here](http://ptpd.sourceforge.net/) it is the standard used for precise time syncing between network nodes (e.g. server and client ,...) and i think you may find the best practical answer there !

Answer (score 16):

First, I think you need to decide if you want to deal with the issue that the C standard leaves the meaning of `time_t` overly vague (it's not necessarily represented in seconds and doesn't even have any meaningful numerical properties like order/comparison). This is contrary to the behavior of **every** existing and historical implementation, where `time_t` is in seconds. Both C and POSIX also allow `time_t` to be a floating point type; as far as I know, no implementations make use of this, and on POSIX it would be rather harmful since the *value* of `time_t` has to be an integer the way it's used in `struct timespec`, etc.

If you decide you're happy assuming `time_t` is always an integral number of seconds since the epoch, i.e. the *values* are meaningful for interchange between systems, then it's just a matter of formatting them. The safest thing to do would be to simply cast to a integer type that's large enough to store any meaningful value and that's the same size on all systems: that would be `int64_t`. Then use whatever normal means you use for serializing `int64_t` in a way that's immune to endian differences.

If on the other hand you want to be "absolutely" portable, you should compute your own `time_t` value for "the epoch" (either the standard one or your own choice of epoch), then use `difftime` to convert to a double representing "seconds since the epoch", and format the `double` with `snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.0f", diff)`. Note that computing a `time_t` value for the epoch in portable C is actually quite difficult because most of the standard functions work in local time, whereas you need universal time. There are tricks you can do with the `gmtime`, `mktime`, and `localtime` functions to figure it out, but it's nontrivial...

Comment: This is a much better version of the answer I was thinking about writing. Thanks for stopping by. +1

Comment: Thanks. I added a paragraph about the "fully portable" approach too.

Comment: Nice answer. Yes, I want to be as portable as possible (having that networks all run on 8-bit-bytes platforms, the range of architectures to support is 'a bit less huge'). The information you provided is very useful. I didn't know that time_t can be a typedef of a floating-point data type.

Comment: That "can" is only in theory. There are no implementations that do it because it has no practical value, and various practical problems.

Comment: As far a C/C++ and Posix are concerned, there is no standard definition of the epoch.  So unless you decide on your own, you may also have problems here.

Comment: POSIX defines the epoch. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_15

Comment: @R.. : http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc750/html/lr1/z2056869.htm#z2028606  I'm sure I'm not the only person here with IBM/3[67]0 programming experience.

Comment: @rici: That's the documentation for some product by SAS, not POSIX. POSIX requires the particular epoch, as noted in the SAS documentation you linked.

Comment: @R.. Yes, since 2008 Posix requires integral types, I believe. But you said "no implementation", not "no Posix implementation", and the 370 definitely use[d] doubles when I used it. I don't know if anyone uses it any more; I certainly don't.

Comment: Anyway, what I was about to suggest was difftime() with his own epoch, convert to integer so you have seconds as an 32-bit integer from a known epoch, exchange the integers in netowrk-byte-order and use that instead of time_t. But it's probably overkill these days.

Comment: Using a 32-bit integer would be pretty stupid; roughly on the same degree of stupidity as using a 2-digit string in the 1970s and 80s was. This is 2012. You have 64-bit integers and they'll be sufficiently large for the lifetime of the universe. Use them.

Answer (score 4):

You could send a textual representation produced by [`strftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime) in combination with `gmtime`. The representation would be a bit larger than a binary representation, but not huge. E.g., the format string `"%Y%j%H%M%S"` produces a 13-byte representation of a moment in time (excluding a NUL character).

**EDIT**: forget about my previous advice to use `ctime`; that uses [`localtime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) and would therefore only work if client and server are in the same timezone. And apparently, `asctime` is unsafe, so use `strftime`.

Comment: `asctime` is deprecated and is specified in such a way that it results in dangerous buffer overflows for years in the distant distant past or future.

Comment: @R..: good to know. Changed my advice to use `strftime` exclusively. That also provides control over the size of the string, so it's better anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You could send it in textual form, with a fixed number of digits. Then you don't have to worry about signs, size incompatibilities, or even byte order.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** There seems to be a library that provides exactly what you are looking for, check out [Apache Portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org/), specifically [this page on time routines](https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.5/group__apr__time.html). Other than that, I would say my answer still provides a way to implement this manually, provided all systems are POSIX.1-2001 compliant.

I'm having a similar problem right now and I think it might be nice to have some instructions on how to go through with this. Note that this solution here should be POSIX.1-2001 compatible (on Ubuntu 14.04, `man tzset` and `man localtime` gives such information, and I haven't used other sources, really).

Use `localtime` to convert the data obtained from your call to `time` into a `struct tm` (see `time.h`):

```
struct tm {
           int tm_sec;         /* seconds */
           int tm_min;         /* minutes */
           int tm_hour;        /* hours */
           int tm_mday;        /* day of the month */
           int tm_mon;         /* month */
           int tm_year;        /* year */
           int tm_wday;        /* day of the week */
           int tm_yday;        /* day in the year */
           int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time */
};
```

Note that `localtime` will set the variable declared as (again, see `time.h`)

```
extern long timezone; //seconds West of UTC
```

Since all types are now known, you can write your own conversion tool to make this data network-portable. Things to consider:

- (Preferrably in your software init), you will have to determine how many bytes your `int` and `long` have (use `sizeof`, of course)
- Based on that information, you could do a host-to-network conversion on each integer field of the `struct tm` (use `htonl` or `htons` - for 64bit types, you will have to write your own) and send that information to the client (in whatever way you like).
  *If you have a time zone difference,* you will also need to convert/send time zone information, i.e. the data stored in the variable `timezone` (see above).
- The client will then have to

  1. Convert the received data into client byte order
  2. Write it into a `struct tm` (if time zones are involved, write the received time zone data into a `long`)
  3. *If time zones are involved*, write the received timezone data into a `long` and compute the time zone difference (compute the difference of the received `timezone` datum and what you get by calling `tzset` locally...), then adjust the `struct tm` variable created in step 2.
  4. Having obtained a `struct tm` adjusted to the client's local time zone, use `mktime` to convert data back into a `time_t`
  5. Account for time zone difference, if there is any.