# Big-endian serialisation of struct timeval

Tags: c, posix, endianness, gettimeofday, timeval

What would be the best way to serialise the `struct timeval` type obtained via the `gettimeofday(2)` call? I would like to stick to some standard, so htobe64(3) and friends will not do. The `time_t` type could possibly be a 64-bit integer and there is no clear way how to serialise those object.

Comment: Isn't the idea of serialisation that endianess isn't relevant anymore? Then look at json or xml or somthing. With those techniques it should be relatively easy. There are many libraries for both.

Comment: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations), specifically the "`YYYYMMDD` T `hhmmss` Z" format (UTC time). If you do need the microsecond accuracy, then "`YYYYMMDD` T `hhmmss.uuuuuu` Z". You can do this by calling `gmtime()` and then formatting it with `strftime()`.

Comment: Perhaps one part of my question which was not explicit was that the serialisation should be in raw binary. Is that achievable without using a designated format, such as JSON or ISO8601?

Comment: Why `htobe64` don't fit your needs? Anyway, you may read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957254/c-c-safest-way-to-send-time-t-over-socket